# VLOOKUP not finding match

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to find data in an Excel table using VLOOKUP. The column from which I am getting my source value, I believe comes from an HTML page cut and paste. 
Although the data exists in the search table, it is not found. If I manually type the same search data over the the original column source data, it will then be found.

Is it possible there is some hidden HTML info in there? How could I clear it out?

Additionally, the lookup value is lastname, firstname: Smith, Sam for example.  I think the space after the comma is NBSP, but I don't know how to figure that out.

Comment: Try removing whitespaces around the lookup value. Say, if the lookup value is in A1, use `TRIM(A1)` instead in the vlookup.

Comment: Thanks Jerry - I did try that.  It's odd, if I retype the lookup value, it works.

Comment: Maybe try the TRIM() and CLEAN() functions maybe, for example B1: `=CLEAN(TRIM(A1))` then copy / paste special > values back over your original column (in my example, col A)

Comment: Sometimes, you have not printable characters such as "newline" that are "dismissed" when you select the content of a (copied) cell. Can explain the weird behaviour.

Comment: Thanks John, I tried Trim as well.

Comment: @user1634700 copy the weird "space" character and in another cell write `=UNICODE(" ")` pasting the "space" in. That will tell you the character code of what you have. It should be `32` for a normal space, and what you have will be something else. When you know what it is, you can Google for "unicode code point {numbers}" and find what character it really is.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of an answer, from OP:

> nbsp is ascii 160.

```
 =TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(D1,CHAR(160),CHAR(32)))
```

will turn it into a regular space.